# Struggling making a Querybuilder with SQL request for Symfony

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

I'm a beginner and I'm doing an app in Symfony, but I have a problem with making a request, can someone help me, please?
I have 2 tables and I need to get the list of user who has a command, I made the SQL request :

```
SELECT c.user_id, u.* FROM commande AS c LEFT JOIN user AS u ON c.user_id = u.id;
```

But I struggle to make the query builder for it, and I wonder if I should make the query in CommandeRepo or UserRepo

[here are the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y74Qq.png)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please get tour here https://stackoverflow.com/tour and then read how to ask good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to retrieve `users who have an order`, so your query should be in the UserRepository.

```
public function getUsersThatHaveAtLeastOneCommand()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    // commandes here is the name of the property in User entity that contains your "commandes"
    $qb->innerJoin('u.commandes', 'c')

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

I think this should be enough to return you users which have made at least one command. But make some test in local to be sure :)